# Investigate uniform convergence of series of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm asked to investigate the uniform convergence of the following series of function :

$$ \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{7}{x^n+5}, x \ge 2 $$

In class we have only seen examples where we could make use of Abel's criterion but this approach clearly fails here. What is the appropriate approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x \ge 2$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ you have
$$
\bigl| \frac{7}{x^n+5} \bigr| = \frac{7}{x^n+5} \le \frac{7}{2^n} \, .
$$
The uniform convergence now follows with the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Comment: That's very helpful. I was not familiar with the Weierstrass M-test but I think I understand how this test works. Is there a simple way to show that $ \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{7}{2^n} \lt \infty $?

Comment: @VonKar: Look up "geometric series" :)

Comment: I did a quick search and this is what I found. The infinite sum $ S $ of the infinite geometric series is given by $ S = \frac{a}{1-r} $ where $ a $ is the fisrt term of the geometric series and $ r $ is the multiplying factor. So for our example we get : $ S = \frac{\frac{7}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 7 $ so the infinite geometric series converge and therefore our series of function converges uniformly. Is this correct?

Comment: @VonKar: Yes. Actually you don't need the value of the series, only the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{2^n}$ is convergent at all.

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely helpful!